# How do I stop USB media from autoplaying pictures and videos in Ubuntu 16.04 running Cinnamon?

Tags: 16.04, usb, cinnamon, autoplay

Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction to find the root cause of this issue or even provide me the answer directly.

**Background:**

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon as my desktop environment.

**Behavior:**

I plug in a USB/Flash/Thumb/ drive into my workstation. As soon as the flashdrive or external HDD/SSD is automounted, the [MPV player](https://mpv.io/) autolaunches and starts flying through all the pictures and playing whatever videos I have on the disk.

**Expected Behavior:**

I am prompted as to what should happen, or nothing happens at all.

My current **Preferred Applications** is set as shown:

[image: screenshot of Preferred Applications dialog]

[image: screenshot of Removable Media options in preferred applications dialog]

Comment: That's very odd - you could try to turn off the "prompt or start programs on media insertion" toggle, and turn it on again. Also make sure that everything is set to "ask what to do", also under "Other media".

Comment: I was too weak on this site back then, but you did indeed help.